# query with wild card on jsonb on postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a table test_jsonb like this:

```
id:integer, meta_data jsonb, version int
```

the table has data as follows:

```
{"id": 99, "file_name": "test.pdf"}
{"id": 101, "file_name": "test2.pdf"}
```

i want to query all the files that has file_name = test.pdf. how do i do it? cant find any good example. please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Query for files named "test.pdf"

```
SELECT *
FROM test_jsonb
WHERE meta_data->>'file_name' = 'test.pdf'
```

Query for test files with all extensions

```
SELECT *
FROM test_jsonb
WHERE meta_data->>'file_name' LIKE 'test.%'
```

Query for files with ".pdf" extension

```
SELECT *
FROM test_jsonb
WHERE meta_data->>'file_name' LIKE '%.pdf'
```